# Java won't compile

Tags: java

I have been getting an error when I try to compile my Java code.
`'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

My directory looks like this: `Computer -> OS(C:) -> Program Files -> Java -> jdk1.8.0_60 -> Bin`

When I type `set path` into CMD I get this: `Path=file:///C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin`

**My question is:** Why isn't `javac` being recognized even after I have changed the path?

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin;`

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am getting this: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin

Comment: wonderful! dear windows need hard reset when you set the `path`, beside the `file:///C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin` is wrong, it should be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;...<the rest stuffs>`

Comment: I have not restarted my computer yet! Perhaps this is this issue?

Comment: if you hate restart, you may have shortcut of `javac.exe` in `c:/windows` or call the `javac` with its full path

Comment: Hard reset of entire Wibdows is not required. Close current console. New console instance get new environmets variables, PATH too

Comment: Why do you show us a picture of your ***JRE*** directory and always write something about ***JDK***? Do you know what you've installed on your machine?

Comment: Oopsie wrong photo, one second

Comment: I have since added another photo

Comment: So, another question ... you've noticed the difference between **Program Files** and **Program Files (x86)**?

Comment: It appears my issue has been inaugurated by my own stupidity, This issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your java is in `Program Files (x86)` not `Program Files`.

You should set path like this,

```
set path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin
echo %path%
```

Moreover it will not set the path forever once you close the cmd the path you has set will just *vanish*. If you want to store the path in your system you should add your path to *system*'s environment variable. You may find [this](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) helpful for adding environment variable.

Comment: I have changed the path via environmental variables to what you stated. When I type echo %path% in CMD I receive:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin;

Comment: However I still am receiving the same error unfortunately, however I appreciate the help

Comment: I have added two photos that may be of help

Comment: I have selected this answer because it is correct. I had accidentally posted the wrong information. Once I realized this everything is now fine

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether your system is `64-bit` or `32-bit` windows. If it is `32-bit` you are doing fine but if it is 64-bit you need to download 64-bit version of jdk and when you install it the java bin should be available in program files not in program files(x86) then set the path from there.

Comment: A 32 bit system doesn't has a **program files(x86)** directory.

Comment: Ah! I did not know because I never used 32-bit system.

Comment: That folder is called "program files" there. You never used a 32-bit system? If yes, then you must be _very_ young :P